# Linux parents parent path to file

Tags: linux, file, bash, parent-child, directory

Possibly this question seems stupid but anyway. I have a script file `/local/bin/app1/script.sh` and I need to know its parents parent directory name `bin`. I know that I can use `${0%/*}` to determine the parent directory name. I'm not familiar with bash so could somebody please help me to figure out parents parent directory name? Many thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just apply the trick once more:

```
parent=${0%/*}
grandparent=${parent%/*}
```

Or, let the shell tell you

```
( cd ../.. ; pwd )
```

Comment: Works good to me and I like this one-line solution. Thanks you.

Answer (score 1):

give you an example, hope it helps:

```
kent$  pwd
/tmp/bin/app

kent$  cat t.sh
#!/bin/bash
a=`dirname $0`
if [ $a = '.' ];then
   a=`pwd`
fi
current=$a
echo "current path:"$current
cd $current
echo "parents' parent:"
awk -F'/' '{print $(NF-1)}' <<<$current

kent$  ./t.sh         
current path:/tmp/bin/app
parents' parent:
bin

kent$  cd /usr

kent$  pwd
/usr

kent$  /tmp/bin/app/t.sh
current path:/tmp/bin/app
parents' parent:
bin
```

so it will return you "bin".